# How to add geo data to an elasticsearch query (elasticsearch 6.4)?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, geo

Please help a complete newbie!

I have an existing elasticsearch index (that's automatically generated from a plugin that populates the index from a database) and I'm trying to visualize some fields geographically (using Kibana's coordinate map). The index has no geolocation data per se. It has a field called "alloc_node" and I know that there are only handful of "alloc_node"s present in the dataset, and I have their geographical coordinates.

Data from the index looks like this (from Kibana's discover tab, truncated):

```
t  _id          MV0JkWYBmQ9JhdzgNzwI
t  _index           slurm
#  _score            - 
t  _type            jobcomp
t  alloc_node           mace
```

e.g. I know that "mace" is located in NYC, lat = 40.73, lon = -73.94. I only have 5 such records where I have to map the node to geo.

Do I have to update the index to visualize this, or can the extra fields be added via a query? How? What would be most efficient? The index is not large for now (but in production could be).

I tried reading the docs, but I'm confused with Mapping types being deprecated in ES 6.x, and the silly things I tried did not work. I feel like this should be such an easy thing to answer for someone with more experience. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To visualize this in Kibana, you have to have a "geo_point" type in your mapping.
A simple way to create such a field in the mapping would be:

```
PUT /slurm
{
  "mappings": {
    "default": {
      "properties": {
        "your_geo_location_field": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when you push(index) a document into index, the "your_geo_location_field"  field should have a "lat" and "lon" float fields, or an array containing the two, For example, this is a valid object:

```
{ 
  "geolocation": {
    "lat": "40.71476752",
    "lon": "-74.01280024"
  }
}
```

Where "geolocation" is an example of such a field.

What you would have to do is create another index with the above mapping,
reindex your current index into the newely created one (with all the documents containing valid objects) and then Kibana will offer you visualization on top of this field.